# Cassandra 4.0 vulnerable log4j mitigation

Tags: cassandra, log4j

Cassandra 4.0 is having log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25 and CVE-2021-44228 is not applicable. however, slf4j-1.7.25 has CVE-2018-8088. How we are addressing Cassandra's vulnerable log4j issue.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Cassandra [uses Logback as the default logger](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/getting_started/configuring.html#logging), not Log4j so it is not affected by the vulnerability identified in [CVE-2021-44228](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228). Cheers!

Comment: However, slf4j-1.7.25 has CVE-2018-8088 vulnerability used in Cassandra 4.0